# ListView.setAdapter "null Object Reference"

Tags: android, json, android-fragment, listview, arrayadapter

Estoy implementando un ListView cargado con una base de Datos Externa, y estoy Obteniendo los datos con un JSON

Este proyecto lo tenia funcionando sin problemas en un Activity, pero al querer implementar el mismo en un fragment me marca estos errores:

Este es el Codigo que tengo en mi Fragment

FragmentNuevas.java

```
public class FragmentNuevas extends Fragment {

private OnFragmentInteractionListener mListener;
ArrayList<Product> arrayList;
ListView lv;
ProgressDialog pdialog = null;
Context context = null;

public FragmentNuevas() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    lv = (ListView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.listView);
    arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
    context = getActivity();

    getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            pdialog = ProgressDialog.show(context, "", "Buscando Noticias...", true);
            new ReadJSON().execute("http://lahuerta.gob.mx/WebService/consulta.php");
        }
    });

    /*lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long l) {
            Product selectedProduct = arrayList.get(position);

            Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), Nuevas.class);
            intent.putExtra("nombre", selectedProduct.getName());
            intent.putExtra("fecha", selectedProduct.getFecha());
            intent.putExtra("contenido", selectedProduct.getPrice());
            intent.putExtra("extra1", selectedProduct.getImage());
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });*/

    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_fragment_nuevas, container, false);
}

class ReadJSON extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String> {
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        return readURL(params[0]);
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String content) {

        pdialog.dismiss();
        try {
            JSONArray jsonarray = new JSONArray(content);
            for(int i =0;i<jsonarray.length(); i++){
                JSONObject productObject = jsonarray.getJSONObject(i);
                arrayList.add(new Product(
                        productObject.getString("nombre"),
                        productObject.getString("contenido"),
                        productObject.getString("extra1"),
                        productObject.getString("fecha")

                ));
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        CustomListAdapter adapter = new CustomListAdapter(
                getActivity(), R.layout.custom_list_layout, arrayList
        );
        lv.setAdapter(adapter); /*Aqui me da Error*/
    }
}

private static String readURL(String theUrl) {
    StringBuilder content = new StringBuilder();
    try {
        // create a url object
        URL url = new URL(theUrl);
        // create a urlconnection object
        URLConnection urlConnection = url.openConnection();
        // wrap the urlconnection in a bufferedreader
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(urlConnection.getInputStream()));
        String line;
        // read from the urlconnection via the bufferedreader
        while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
            content.append(line + "\n");
        }
        bufferedReader.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return content.toString();
}

// TODO: Rename method, update argument and hook method into UI event
public void onButtonPressed(Uri uri) {
    if (mListener != null) {
        mListener.onFragmentInteraction(uri);
    }
}

@Override
public void onAttach(Context context) {
    super.onAttach(context);
    if (context instanceof OnFragmentInteractionListener) {
        mListener = (OnFragmentInteractionListener) context;
    } else {
        throw new RuntimeException(context.toString()
                + " must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener");
    }
}

@Override
public void onDetach() {
    super.onDetach();
    mListener = null;
}

/**
 * This interface must be implemented by activities that contain this
 * fragment to allow an interaction in this fragment to be communicated
 * to the activity and potentially other fragments contained in that
 * activity.
 * <p>
 * See the Android Training lesson <a href=
 * "http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html"
 * >Communicating with Other Fragments</a> for more information.
 */
public interface OnFragmentInteractionListener {
    // TODO: Update argument type and name
    void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri);
}
```

}

Me marca un error en esta linea:

la Linea 108 en donde da el error es:   `lv.setAdapter(adapter);`

El LogCat es este:

> E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                     Process: mx.gob.lahuerta.oficiadepartes, PID: 18201
>                     java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void
>   android.widget.ListView.setAdapter(android.widget.ListAdapter)' on a
>   null object reference
>
> ```
>                   at mx.gob.lahuerta.oficiadepartes.FragmentNuevas$ReadJSON.onPostExecute(FragmentNuevas.java:108)
>                   at mx.gob.lahuerta.oficiadepartes.FragmentNuevas$ReadJSON.onPostExecute(FragmentNuevas.java:81)
>                   at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:667)
>                   at android.os.AsyncTask.-wrap1(AsyncTask.java)
>                   at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:684)
>                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
>                   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
>                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
>                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
> ```
>
> Application terminated.

Comment: @Elenasys te deje un comentario

Comment: Hubieras dejado los errores originales para tener una correcta referencia de la pregunta. En cuanto a este error, el ListView con id listview no se encuentra en el layout que carga la Activity a traves de setContentView(), o se encuentra en fragment_fragment_nuevas.xml???

Comment: agregue nueva respuesta con el nuevo error, saludos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Agrega el contexto, en este caso el de la Activity para que puedas ejecutar los métodos, por ejemplo para obtener el contexto:

```
context = getActivity();   //this;
```

Para ejecutar `runOnUiThread()` :

```
getActivity().runOnUiThread()....
```

Al convertir tu `Activity` a `Fragment`, el `Fragment` esta relacionado a la `Activity` que lo contiene, por lo tanto:

**Para obtener el contexto dentro de un `Fragment` lo realizas mediante el método `getActivity()`**.

Comment: Ok muchas gracias, solo me queda el error de:                                                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                pdialog = ProgressDialog.show(context, "", "Buscando Noticias...", true);
                new ReadJSON().execute("http://lahuerta.gob.mx/WebService/consultanuevas.php");
            }
        });   este dice "Can not resolve method runOnUiThread (anonymous java.lang.runnable)"

Comment: El error de que ? =)

Comment: Error:(54, 9) error: cannot find symbol method runOnUiThread(<anonymous Runnable>)

Comment: getActivity().runOnUiThread()....

Comment: =).. Ahora me mostro otro error:   arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
Error:(50, 9) error: unreachable statement
Error:(62, 5) error: missing return statement

Comment: Ahora me mostro otro error: arrayList = new ArrayList<>();

Comment: Error:(50, 9) error: unreachable statement                                                Error:(62, 5) error: missing return statement

Comment: Ahora me mostro otro error: arrayList = new ArrayList<>(); Error:(50, 9) error: unreachable statement Error:(62, 5) error: missing return statement

Comment: Algun consejo para este problema?

Comment: Algun consejo para este problema

Comment: Ese es otro tipo de problema, agrega tu código aquí o en otra pregunta.

Comment: Ya agregue el codigo!.. Espero y puedas ayudarme

Answer (score 1):

En cuanto al error

> android.widget.ListView.setAdapter(android.widget.ListAdapter)' on a
>   null object reference

Se debe a que no encuentra la referencia del `ListView` en el layout contenedor, en realidad encuentra dentro del layout que carga el Fragment, en este caso `fragment_fragment_nuevas.xml`  realiza este cambio:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_fragment_nuevas, container, false);

    lv = (ListView)view.findViewById(R.id.listView);
    arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
    context = getActivity();

    getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            pdialog = ProgressDialog.show(context, "", "Buscando Noticias...", true);
            new ReadJSON().execute("http://lahuerta.gob.mx/WebService/consulta.php");
        }
    });


    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    return view; 
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias... Error corregido @Elenasys :) y disculpa tanto enredo

Comment: Me alegra hayas corregido todos los problemas, saludos! @SharlyInfinitywars